# safely deleting volume(Ubuntu partion)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I apologize if the question sounds too naive. I have a disk partition with Ubuntu (not working) installed on (on a windows 10 based laptop). I want to delete the whole partition and rewrite the resulting freed space. I have no file I need to backup. Can I safely use the "Delete volume" option from Windows? will the deleted volume simply become unallocated memory I can use to intall Ubuntu again or is there some delicate issue I am unaware of?

Thank you in advance

Comment: "Can I safely use the "Delete volume" option from Windows?"  That's a windows related question, not Ubuntu. 1 thing to remember: Windows does NOT tell you if a partition is something other than a Windows partition. And always have a backup you know you can restore ;-)

Comment: If you have `grub` installed on your machine, and it points to that partition (thru MBR) you'll find your `grub` no longer works if you delete the partition (*and you may not be able to reboot into windows*). As you haven't told us how you were using the partition, we can't know.  Yes you can delete it, but if you were using grub, you must tell your windows to take possession of the MBR so you can reboot it (*which is a windows issue, not a Ubuntu issue*)

Comment: Thank you both. I can tell which partition I have to delete from its size. The only thing I could lose is the windows licence but it should be safely associated to th BIOS if I'm not mistaken. I do have grub, which does not appear at reboot though so that Windows still seems to be ruling: I fear something went wrong doing the Ubuntu installation and before doing complicared stuff I would like to just try delete and reinstall if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you install Ubuntu again it's OK to delete the partition.
2. If you want to use for something else:
   Boot into the recovery mode of your Windows to access Command Prompt
   or
   Get the original installation disc of your Windows version to access System Recovery, go to command prompt and run:

```
bootrec /FixMbr
bootrec /FixBoot
bootrec /ScanOs
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

to get the Windows Boot Loader back.

3. If you have some doubt about the partition then boot with Ubuntu installation DVD/USB and do it from there.

Note: If You have some unusual partition scheme please post the details of the partitions and the Disks.

Comment: thank you. about 1) good news! about 2) no. about 3) the Ubuntu installation DVD redirects me to the "emergency" grub prompt which does not allow me to access ubuntu. Since, during the Ubuntu installation, I might have messed things up a bit, I would like to try to "reset " everything before eventually attemlting more complicated stuff.

Comment: Did it. It did not solve my main issue as I was hoping but it was a step ahead for sure. thank you for your ckear answer

Comment: Please give more details about the problem/doubt.

Comment: I will soon create a separate question for the main issue. I feel it's easier if I break it down into sub-questions. The problem is likely to be grub preventing access to Ubuntu installation USB anyway